# JavaScript - How can you pass global variables between .js files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and programming in general. I think I'm going about this the wrong way but I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do and how I'm doing it. It's not working.

I made a page with five  boxes that you can click. When you click one, it will run a function stored in one js file and look through cases to find the one that matches, then change the text in the text box as well as the choices in the five  boxes below. I think I'm having trouble with global variables not carrying over from one included .js file to another.

I can't think of another way of doing this. I can't just return a single variable since I need to change around 5 separate variables for each case statement for each choice. Is there a better way of carrying this information back and forth than these $choice variables that don't seem to work?

file 1.js

```
var $choice1 = "0";
var $choice2 = "0";
var $choice3 = "0";
var $choice4 = "0";
var $choice5 = "0";

//Main Body - start doing stuff once the page has loaded    
$( document ).ready(function() {    

//Run once
NewArea("newgame");

$("#choice1").click(function() {
    NewArea($choice1);
    });

$("#choice2").click(function() {
    NewArea($choice2);
    });

$("#choice3").click(function() {
    NewArea($choice3);
    });

$("#choice4").click(function() {
    NewArea($choice4);
    });

$("#choice5").click(function() {
    NewArea($choice5);
    });

});
```

and then we have file 2.js

```
function NewArea($area) {
    switch($area)
    {
    case "newgame": //Start of the game
        $("#textbox").html("blah");
        $("#choice1").html("Look around");
            $choice1 = "look_1";
        $("#choice2").html("Listen around");
            $choice1 = "listen_1";
        $("#choice3").html("Smell around");
            $choice1 = "smell_1";
        $("#choice4").html("Feel around");
            $choice1 = "feel_1";
        $("#choice5").html("Taste around");
            $choice1 = "taste_1";
        break;

    case "look_1":
        $("#textbox").html("blah2");
        $("#choice1").html("");
            $choice1 = "0";
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: JS files simply get included to the page at the point you include them. Variables aren't being passed back and forth between pages. It's all one document.

Comment: include `1.js` before `2.js`

Comment: Do be aware, though they're great for quick and dirty stuff, you [should avoid global variables](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals) for serious or production-level projects.

Comment: Use Object literals instead of just global variables. Global variables are not advisable

Comment: Try using: var NewArea = function ($area)... Function declaration get hoisted to the top before you declare your variables in your case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at least consider namespacing the global variables for clarity and slightly cleaner code.  You can also make it an array rather than discrete variables so you can easily expand them if necessary (bearing in mind your indexing from your ids will be off by 1, since arrays are 0-indexed):

```
var myGame = {
    choices: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
};
```

As others have mentioned, the key is that this snippet of code loads before your file2.js (either by loading it in a separate file before file1.js and file2.js, or ensuring file1.js loads before file2.js).

You mention you don't know another way of doing this, and it seems like you're using a DOM-gnostic jQuery approach, so other things that may work (though not necessarily better) are:

- Storing the choices in hidden input fields.  This will clutter your DOM instead of the global namespace. ;)  So you can have `<input type='hidden' value='0' name='choice1Value'/>` and then get/set the value in there.
- You can also use the jQuery [data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function to store the value on each choice: `$('#choice1').data('choice', 0);` for example.

There are other refactorings you could consider as well, but it depends on the structure of your files and how you load them, but hopefully this provides a few ideas on different approaches.

Comment: var Aro = {
 choice: ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
 };

had to get rid of the ; after the choice array. Also, in my original code I am setting $choice1 each time instead of $choice1, $choice2, respectively which was what was causing my problem. 

I did some reading about what namespacing is and now I understand it (at a basic level). This should be very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: @Aro Oh you're right, sorry about that.  I'll updated.  Glad to help, though!

Answer (score 1):

use it like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' > 
  window.$choice1 = "0";
  window.$choice2 = "0"; 
  window.$choice3 = "0";
  window.$choice4 = "0";
  window.$choice5 = "0";
</script>
```

then below link `file1.js` and `file2.js`

Comment: you don't really need window here